# Meaning of "in so far as"

Tags: meaning

> Groups such as Hizb ut-Tahrir and Tablighi Jamaat play a peripheral role in so far as both men and women may be radicalised as they gravitate toward their teachings.

What's the meaning of the above sentence? In particular, I don't know what *in so far as* here means.

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. Did you try a web search on this phrase? It should have turned up, for example, http://grammarist.com/words/insofar/ . If the dictionary definitions are still unclear to you, then we may be able to help, but please indicate the research you have already attempted so that it is not duplicated.

Answer (score 0):

[Collins Dictionary](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/in-so-far-as) gives this meaning for **in so far as**

> to the degree or extent that

Therefore your sentence would become

> Groups such as Hizb ut-Tahrir and Tablighi Jamaat play a peripheral role *to the degree that* both men and women may be radicalised as they gravitate toward their teachings.

Comment: If it's a large degree, then that 'peripheral' comes into question. Looks like a poorly phrased, or deliberately obfuscatory sentence to me.

Comment: I think in OP's exact context it's not so much *to the extent/degree*. More a matter of *if we consider **only** the scope of the following context*.

Answer (score 0):

[Considering that](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/inasmuch) “in so far as” and “inasmuch as” share similar meanings (meaning #1 of “inasmuch as”), perhaps the author of the sentence (mistakenly?) assumed that “in so far as” also shared meaning #1.1 of “inasmuch as,” (i.e., “considering that”; “since”; [also “seeing that”; “in light of the fact that”; “because”]).

That interpretation would render:

“Groups such as Hizb ut-Tahrir and Tablighi Jamaat play a peripheral role **inasmuch as/considering that/since** both men and women may be radicalised as they gravitate toward their teachings.,” and avoid the “peripheral” issue mentioned by @WayfaringStranger .

(I just saw @FumbleFinger 's suggestion, which predates and, I believe, mirrors mine [but honestly didn't inspire it, considering that I was writing mine as s/he was posting his/hers])